# why setOnClickListener not working for inflated button?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-inflate

I am a beginner and I am inflating the button from `tab_fragment.xml`, when i am trying to setOnClickListener to that button, it is not working

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.line1));
    Button button= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(new Tab(), "two");
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
```

this is my 
tab_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/line1"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:text="some text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. Got it. The button is part of the fragment layout. So you don't have an instance of the button in the activity class. If you want to handle the button click behaviour on the activity class, you could make the activity to implement OnClickListener. Then override the onAttach() method from fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(activity instanceof OnClickListener)
        mListener = (OnClickListener) activity;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mListener = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

then on the onCreateView method:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    return v;
}
```

Also, move the logic from onClick (from fragment) in onClick() from activity like below:

```
Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
          // move your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in the fragment class:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(new Tab(), "two");
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to know why its not working when i called from `MainActivity`

Comment: Do you want to add the listener on the button from activity? Sorry, but I didn't understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I want to add the listener from the activity not from fragment. I can do with adding listener from fragment, but i want to know why its not working from activity